# How to display the city name only in auto suggestion with google map using API?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I need to display the city name alone in auto  suggestion with google map while enter the city name in text box.
In my web site, I have using google api for location search. it shows city name with country name.But I want to show only city name alone in auto suggestion results.

```
Here is my code :    

   s = jQuery('<input type="text" value="' + n.html() + '" />');
   var options_auto = {
                          types: ['(cities)'],
                          componentRestrictions: {country: "jp"}
                      };
    x = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(s[0], options_auto);
```